# Golang: calculate how many goroutines are started by worker itself?

Tags: go, goroutine

Here is my problem: a caller will create several goroutines to run my code `doWork`,

```
go func() {
    for data := range dataSet {
        doWork(data)
    }
}()
```

And now, I want to count how many goroutines are started to do this work, though I can not modify or read data from the caller. How can I achieve this?

[update] `doWork` is passed to caller, for example:

```
   doWork := func(i int) {
        testArray[i]++
        ...
    }

   Parallelize(workerNumber, doWork)
```

So I am planning to use a global variable as counter.

Comment: How do you count a goroutine that starts and finishes before doWork returns?

Comment: You may use [`runtime.NumGoroutine()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#NumGoroutine) to query the number of goroutines that currently exist. It may help if you can restrict not to launch new goroutines in other parts of your code (and not to finish any meanwhile), else it won't be "accurate" (it won't be what you want). You won't get better help than that unless the caller gives you more "insight". And actually you shouldn't care. Correctness of your code should not depend on how many goroutines are calling it: it's either _safe_ for concurrent use (and then it doesn't matter), or not.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you really want to know the count or are you just want to control them? Because that you can better do with channels or a syncgroup

Comment: I want to count the goroutine number, it's part of my metrics

Answer (score 2):

`runtime.NumGoroutines()` should give you a global number, so let's assume you cannot rely on that and you need to count how many goroutines were started by this specific procedure, and not the possibly more complex application.

One solution could be, as you stated, using a global counter. Remember that there are races in this case, therefore you are better using synchronization methods, for example by using [atomic operations](https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters).

Personally, I do not love globals, therefore a solution that I'd like more could be to use a closure to produce a pair (function, countingvariable) by using a maker function (untested code):

```
func makeCounted(n int) ([]uint64, func(int)) {
    var counters []uint64 = make([]uint64, n)
    return counters, func(i int) {
        atomic.AddUint64(&counters[i], 1)
        fmt.Println("Doing stuff")
    }
}

howMany, doWork := makeCounted()
Parallelize(workers, doWork)
```

In the case in which `n` is unknown (`len(dataSet)` is unknown), you will have to grow dynamically the size of counters, but you will probably need something like `sync.Mutex`.